# Typed Reactive Forms in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting the below error when using Typed Reactive Forms in Angular 14 and I have defined a type that maps a model to a strict form group. The error only occurs when using the Date or Blob type.
PS: I use Angular 14.

```
Error: src/app/sumarios/submission-sumario/submission-sumario.component.ts:903:7 - error TS2740: Type 'FormControl<Date>' is missing the following properties from type 'FormGroup<ControlsOf<Date>>': controls, registerControl, addControl, removeControl, and 2 more.

903       dataCriacao: new FormControl(sumario.dataCriacao),
```

Source:

```
export type ControlsOf<T extends Record<any, any>> = {
  [P in keyof T]?: T[P] extends Record<any, any>
  ? T[P] extends (infer U)[] ? (U extends Record<any, any> ? FormArray<FormGroup<ControlsOf<U>>> : FormArray<FormControl<U>>) : FormGroup<ControlsOf<T[P]>>
  : FormControl<T[P]>
}
```

[image]

Class:

[image]

[EDIT]

[Here is the basic example demonstrating the error](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ybqndv?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've included the example link above on stackblitz.

Answer (score 1):

Do `ControlsOf` is your concern? If not, you can try to replace with [ngx-mf](https://github.com/iamguid/ngx-mf).

Here is example [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-mf)

Here is more information about: [4 Problems of Angular 14 Typed Forms and How to Fix Them](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/why-new-angular-14-typed-forms-isnt-good-and-how-to-fix-it-1ffebf193df)

Comment: yes, it seems that the function only recognizes primitive type and class.  The object, such as Date or Blob, does not.  It seems that you have to adjust the function to recognize object.

Comment: I've included the example link above on stackblitz.